# How can solve to calculate position of image for any random point and random paraxial rays?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, optics, geometric-optics

I am a high school student and I have a confusion related to optics {image formation via spherical mirrors) in all my books they say to find location of image its convenient to use the following rays"

1. incident on pole
2. parallel to principal axis
3. passing through focus
4. passing through center of curvature

but when they are doing the derivation they already consider that for paraxial rays an image will form, i.e they already consider that paraxial rays from any point will almost converge or appears to converge at a single point .In other words can anyone derive the mirror formula by selecting any two random paraxial rays (other than mentioned above)?

[image: This image will clear everyone what I am trying to ask]

because it will then convince me that we can treat any paraxial rays to be meeting at almost at single point and forming an image.

In short: please solve for location of image by considering any random point and random paraxial rays.

Comment: *In other words can anyone derive the mirror formula by selecting any two random paraxial rays (other than mentioned above)?* Your question is unclear to me particular as an answer which has a ray diagram that you have accepted does not shown the incoming rays to be paraxial (parallel to the principle axis). *. . . please solve for location of image by considering any random point and random paraxial rays.* Any random point on what?  Any point off the principle axis can only produce one paraxial ray as all other rays will be at an angle to the principle axis.

Comment: but paraxial rays are the rays which are closer to the principal axis so that we can treat rays from any point to be converging at a single point they need not to be parallel to it

Comment: @Farcher I am asking to solve for the mirror equation for a point which lies above the principal axis by selecting rays which are random and have small inclination angle with principal axis(i.e paraxial rays)

Comment: I do understand what you are asking but what I, and others, have said that it is a difficult derivation and will lead to the result that the position of the point image will depend on the angle of inclination of the rays relative to the principal axis. This means that a series of point images will be formed and the image which is the sum of the point images will be distorted.

Comment: so, Is the assumption taken in all textbooks? even at higher level? should I just grab as it is for now that the x cordinate for all points of the vertical object will be the same??

Comment: @Farcher But the answers that I have here,,,,I don't understand their mathematics

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I try to "realize"  your idea

- C center of spherical mirror Radius R
- F focus at $~\frac R2$

**Image A'-B'**

the ray B-1 is return to F, the intersection between the rays F-1 and C-B is the point B' so you obtain the Image A'-B'

**Image A"-B"**

you send a ray B-2 with angle $~\alpha~$ this ray is return back with the angle $~\beta~$  between  B-2 and F-2 . where $~\cos(\beta)=\cos(2\,\varphi+\alpha)~$

you send another ray B_3  that return back with $~\beta_2~$ .

the intersection between those two rays is the point B", those you obtain the image A"-B".

is this what you wanted to do ??

Notice for $~\alpha=0~$ you obtain the image A'-B'

Comment: I didn't understand the maths,,,how cos(β)=cos(2φ+α) ??

Comment: also how B⃗ 2=[cos(α)−sin(α)]F⃗ 2=[cos(2φ)sin(2φ)]??

Comment: Probably wrong i will  delete the edit section

Comment: I still didn't get that how your answer "Proves" That the paraxial rays from topmost point will converge at a single point?

Comment: Sorry I can’t answer this , try your own answer

Answer (score 0):

Diagram for the mirror system.
[image]

$x_1 = x_0 + t_0*\beta_0 $ with $\theta´ = -\theta$

$\beta_0 -  \beta_1 = \theta -\theta´= 2*\theta$

$\beta_1 = \phi - \theta$

$\phi = -\frac{x_1}{R_1}$

combining these equations you obtain

$\beta_1 = -\beta_0 - \frac{2*x_1}{R_1}\,$ which is the reflection ray-tracing equation and propagation of the ray is

$x_2 = x_1+ t_1*\beta_1 = x_0 + t_0*\beta_0 + t_1 * \beta_1$

Reference:

FUNDAMENTALS OF GEOMETRICAL OPTICS, Virendra N. Mahajan, SPIE Press, 2014

Comment: sorry, But I didn't understand your mathematics,,,,,does you answer "proves" that the paraxial rays from topmost point will converge at a single point??